# Internal Error at Pitney Bowes signup for Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, pitney-bowes

I'm trying to add a new 'Validate Address' service on Bluemix and must register (at Pitney Bowes) to receive my API key. I get this error from the link provided by Bluemix portal when I try to access the sign up page. Is this based on my Bluemix ID or Pitney Bowes related?

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

After registering a support ticket with Pitney Bowes, the issue seems to have been that the link provided initially from Bluemix > add Service > Validate Address to Developer Registration Page was 'http' and needed to be updated to 'https'.

This link seems to have been corrected and works as intended now.